# setLocation not working on class extending JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a class named "Player" which extends JPanel. The class has the attributes x and y (which might be the problem but I can't figure it out). When I run the next code it sets the location of the JPanel to (100, 100):

```
private void initGamePanel() {
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    gamePanel.setVisible(true);
    gamePanel.setLayout(null);

    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.setLocation(100, 100);
    jPanel.setSize(100, 100);
    jPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    gamePanel.add(player);
}
```

But when I do the same with the "Player" class, the position stays at (0, 0):

```
private void initGamePanel() {
    gamePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    gamePanel.setVisible(true);
    gamePanel.setLayout(null);

    player = new Player();
    player.setLocation(100, 100);
    player.setSize(100, 100);
    player.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    gamePanel.add(player);
}
```

And another thing: when I set the x and y of player in the constructor, the position is equal to those values.

Comment: `The class has the attributes x and y (which might be the problem` - it could be, especially if you have getX() and getY() methods, since these are already implemented by a JPanel and should not be overridden. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That might be the problem. Let me take a look, if I still can't find the problem, I will post more information.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem :D

Comment: This was my first question so if you want me to validate your answer (or however you call that) you have to explain that first lol.

Comment: Normally I would post an answer (not a comment) but I just made a guess (glad it was right). Then you would "accept" an answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer that best help solve the problem so people know the problem has been solved. I added an answer so you can practice "accepting" answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The class has the attributes x and y (which might be the problem

It could be, especially if you have `getX()` and `getY()` methods, since these are already implemented by a JPanel and should not be overridden.

Not sure if you really need the x/y attributes since you can just set the location of the component directly.

If you need these attributes for another reason then they should have a more descriptive name to avoid confusion with the class variables.